# Spring Boot Rest - How to accept multiple headers

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-rest

I am using Spring Boot V2.2.2.RELEASE and doing API versioning using custom headers. I developed small endpoint like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student/header", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2", "X-API-VERSION=1"})
public StudentV1 headerV2() {
    return new StudentV1("Bob Charlie");
}
```

When I hit `curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/student/header -H 'x-api-version: 1'`, I get the error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-01-13T09:20:20.087+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/student/header"
}
```

If I used `headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2"}`, then it works, but if I used `headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2", "X-API-VERSION=1"}`, then things stop working.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student/header", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2"})
public StudentV1 headerV2() {
  return new StudentV1("Bob Charlie");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2", "X-API-VERSION=1"}` both headers must be present.

Try using one mapping per header and then forward to your service impl.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student/header", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=1"})
public StudentV1 headerV1() {
    return serviceImpl.headerV1();
}

@GetMapping(value = "/student/header", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2"})
public StudentV1 headerV2() {
    return serviceImpl.headerV2();
}
```

Comment: you'll need to implement custom handlers... https://codeboje.de/spring-mvc-argument-mapping-basics/

Comment: which version should be called when both headers are present? Or just add a third mapping with headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2", "X-API-VERSION=1"}

Comment: if I pass version 1 then logic related to version 1 should be called and I pass version 1 then logic related to version 2. I suspect I need to provide if else at controller which looks bad to me

Comment: @Alexander - try using one mapping per header and then forward to a common service impl. - Could you please share some code ?